# Changing DOM based on Google Calendar resource availablity

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

Thanks for any help that you provide in advance! I've been learning to code for the last year, and I'm actively building my first app.

I'm using: - Front End: HTML, CSS, Bootstrap (with MDBootstrap add-on), jQuery - Back End: Node.JS (with Express, Passport, Cookie-session) and MongoDB

My question I believe is relatively simple, but I just haven't been able to piece together what I need to build to realise my vision for this app. Although the front end is more complex, the fundamental functionality of this app is to authenticate users (using Google Sign-in) and then display either RED or GREEN based on a shared Google Calendar's event data.

On the Back End, I'm authenticating users then pulling their Google profile data. Authenticating using Google gives me access to an AccessToken and a RefreshToken. Everything up to this point is fine and seems to work well (at least for a first attempt).

Anyway, the problem is getting access to the private (shared between colleagues) Calendar Event data on the Front End so I can set up logic to choose what is displayed to the user. I can't seem to be able to make an API call because I need the Access Token/Refresh Token on the Front End and I can't see how I can pass that data through. I assume that because the code for the API call is on the Front End, this might not be the best way to go about this?

I'm partial to stripping down the app and starting again, but I don't know if what I've built so far is already on the right path, or if I need to follow a different path altogether? Really all I'm looking for is a guidance on a structure/path that I should follow to get this done as I'm lacking a lot of direction at the moment.

I'd really appreciate anyones help here.

Thanks all

Comment: Let me clear something, you're using NodeJS for your backend services then pass the data to UI using Javascript?

Comment: @jess yes, that’s essentially what I’d like to do. I want to query the API on the backend, get a response then manipulate the DOM based on the response I get.